# How can I both cache and compress responses?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, compression

Several of my responses, both `GET` pages and `POST` replies, implement `[OutputCache]` for short durations.

I also enabled site-wide compression with the following function:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Implement HTTP compression
    var app = (HttpApplication) sender;

    // Retrieve accepted encodings
    var encodings = app.Request.Headers.Get("Accept-Encoding");
    if (encodings == null)
        return;
    encodings = encodings.ToLower();

    if (encodings.Contains("gzip"))
    {
        app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(app.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    }
    else if (encodings.Contains("deflate"))
    {
        app.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(app.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
    }
}
```

The problem is that it tries to re-compress cached files. This means any time I send a cached response, it gets compressed into garbage.

I considered trying to look at `app.Response.Headers["Content-Encoding"]` for existing compression, but I get a `PlatformNotSupported` exception. How can I enable compression without removing my cached responses?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would move that logic into `Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute`, which will only be executed if the page was actually executed. In such a case, the compressed output along with the Content-Encoding header will be cached and sent as the response. Subsequent cache hits will serve the compressed content and header without the Filter assignment.

Second, you're gonna want to let the Cache know this URL varies by content-encoding. You need to add this line in there (before the short-circuit):

```
app.Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("encoding");
```

as well as override `HttpApplication.GetVaryByCustomString`, along the lines of:

```
protected override GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext ctx, string custom) {
    if (custom != "encoding") return base.GetVaryByCustomString(ctx, custom);

    var acceptEncodings = ctx.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
    if (acceptEncodings.Contains("gzip")) return "gzip";
    if (acceptEncodings.Contains("deflate")) return "deflate";
    return "unencoded";
}
```

Lastly, you should tell clients that they need to vary their cache on the same header. In the case of Accept-Encoding, it's unlikely a user agent will vary this, but it's the Right Thing to do. Alas, [some browsers](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94369) ignore this anyway.

```
app.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
```